# how to convert mp4 to webm file using ffmpeg in php on centos

Tags: php, ffmpeg, webm

**i have done installation. after then i have using following code to convert mp4 to webm using ffmpeg on centos.**

but it does not convert and also didn't throw any error.what is wrong with my code else am i forgot anythink in installation.

Thanks Anvanced

**Webm convertion Code**

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "blank.mp4" -acodec libvorbis -b:a 96k -ac 2 -vcodec libvpx -b:v 400k -f webm -s 384x216 "blank.webm"
```

Comment: i think you should not use ffmpeg.exe ,,, you should use /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg   or  only ffmpeg

Comment: You can run shell commands like that: `$result = \`ffmpeg -i "blank.mp4" -acodec libvorbis -b:a 96k -ac 2 -vcodec libvpx -b:v 400k -f webm -s 384x216 "blank.webm"\`;` and `$result` contains the output generated by the command.

Comment: ffmpeg.exe is for windows...

Comment: i have checkout using which ffmpeg.output like /usr/bin/ffmpeg

Comment: do you use exec function for php ??

Comment: ya i have use it below this exec($cmd);$cmd contains that code

Comment: i got this while run above code $result in php Warning: exec(): Cannot execute a blank command in /home/wwwoktakes/public_html/oktakes/admin/ajax/submitted_project_action.php on line 72

Comment: i have put like this, $result = `"$ffmpeg" -i "$video" -acodec libvorbis -b:a 96k -ac 2 -vcodec libvpx -b:v 400k -f webm -s 384x216 "$webmpath"`;

Comment: still now i am battling with this concept..anyone have ideas bro..

Comment: Does the unscripted `ffmpeg` command work when you manually run it in a console?

Comment: i am new to this. so can you tell clearly bro

Comment: how to check libvpx installed or not in linux centos

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$video = $ffmpeg->open('video.mp4');
$video
    ->filters()
    ->resize(new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(320, 240))
    ->synchronize();
$video
    ->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(10))
    ->save('frame.jpg');
$video
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\WMV(), 'export-wmv.wmv')
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\WebM(), 'export-webm.webm');
```

https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg